# CKEditor 4 and figure widget, how to express "title caption" or two figcaptions?

Tags: html, ckeditor

The [CKEditor 4.3 demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo#widgets) show an example of widget for work with HTML5 `figure` tag.

As a user (editing the demo text) I can not edit a second `figcaption` (one before image, as "figure title", and other after image, as caption): when edit (by CKEditor's source code) before, it goes after, when  I add a paragraph (p tag) before image, also goes after. So, there are no way to user express distinct "head-caption" and "foot-caption", always CKeditor put after image.

**There are some configuration to enable "head-captions"?**

---

The edited source code:

```
 <figure class="caption" style="float:right">
    <figcaption>HEAD - Test</figcaption>
    <img alt="Apollo-CSM-LM" 
     src="http://b.cksource.com/a/1/img/demo/apollo-csm-lm.png" width="200" />
    <figcaption>FOOT - Apollo CMS-LM spacecraft</figcaption>
 </figure>
```

So, CKEditor transforms into,

```
 <figure class="caption" style="float:right">
    <img alt="Apollo-CSM-LM" 
     src="http://b.cksource.com/a/1/img/demo/apollo-csm-lm.png" width="200" />
    <figcaption>HEAD - Test</figcaption>
    <figcaption>FOOT - Apollo CMS-LM spacecraft</figcaption>
 </figure>
```

Idem with `<p>HEAD - Test</p>`. If I use only the `<figcaption>HEAD - Test</figcaption>`, it also goes after image (impossible to express a "before img caption").

NOTE-1: "head" and "foot" `figcaptions` are both valid in HTML5, as [showed in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2HDY/).

NOTE-2: another problem is a caption with more than one paragraph. CKEditor transforms it in a BR, that is not what author need in a typical journal.

NOTE-3: for this related needs — use of paragraphs, use of "before image" caption, and use of two captions —, see all needs of a typical journal at an stable standard like [JATS fig element](http://jats.nlm.nih.gov/publishing/tag-library/1.0/n-8ju0.html), or  millions of article examples at [PMC](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/).

Comment: Although the browser might render it, according to the spec it seems that you can only have one figcaption: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/figure.html#figure If you check with http://validator.w3.org/nu/ you'll see that it states that it's invalid HTML5

Comment: I need "head and/or foot", no matter about the tag names: can be two figcaptions, or an figcaption and some "legend title" tag (exists?)... I think this is a point of HTML5 spec under discussion, figure have legend, and legend "represents a title or explanatory caption" (your link text), and this "or" is not a "xor".  [This other W3C latest spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element) say "the first or last child of a figure element" (a xor?), sure not obliging "only the last", as CKeditor widget do.

Comment: I don't know if this is a point under discussion, just that the statement that are both valid in HTML5 doesn't seems correct at the moment, or the nu validator handles your testcase wrong.

Comment: @PeterKrauss i want to implement the same.Did it work for that. I also want title and caption both with image.

Comment: i updated plugin code but after render it sending bot figcaption to the end...here it updated plugin code -> var template = '<img alt="" src="" />',
  templateBlock = new CKEDITOR.template(
   '<figure class="{captionedClass}">' +
    '<figcaption class="title">{captionPlaceholder}</figcaption>' +
     template +
    '<figcaption>{captionPlaceholder}</figcaption>' +
   '</figure>' ),
  alignmentsObj = { left: 0, center: 1, right: 2 },
  regexPercent = /^\s*(\d+\%)\s*$/i;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - no, there is no config option for that.

Some details - you're using the [image widget](http://ckeditor.com/addon/image2), which is supposed to handle `figure.caption>img+figcaption` case. Specific widget may not work with every possible input and it happens in this case.

If you want to remove that limitation there are two ways:

1. Don't use the [image widget](http://ckeditor.com/addon/image2) by disabling it or remove `class="caption"` from your HTML. For example this HTML will not be changed:

   ```
   <figure>
       <figcaption>1</figcaption>
       <img src="..." ...>
       <figcaption>2</figcaption>
   </figure>
   ```

   Also, the enter key will work in a standard way inside `figcaption`s (will create `<p>` tags).
2. The other way, if you want to use the [image widget](http://ckeditor.com/addon/image2), is to modify its behaviour. In case of simple widgets it can be done without touching widget code, inn the [`widgetDefinition`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-widgetDefinition) event listener. However, image widget is pretty complex, so you'd have to change its code.

   - To change enter key behaviour, just change the [`widgetDefinition.editables.caption.allowedContent`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.nestedEditable.definition-property-allowedContent) - it has to contain a `p` tag. This part can be done in `widgetDefinition` listener.
   - In order to be able to use two captions, you'd have to add another [nested editable](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.definition-property-editables) and modify the [plugin code](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/image2/plugin.js), because it handles only `img+figcaption` case.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot (!), I will use your item-2. About item-1, not works -- if you try by changing source-code, the `figure` structure is destroyed (`figure` and `figurecaption` tags disappears after class attribute removed).

Comment: CKEditor strips `figure` and `figcaption`, because they are not allowed. Read about the [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) to learn more.

Comment: Sorry my english, I not expressed well... Is only a little correction in your text of item-1 (I edited to show): old "this HTML will not be changed" is false, new "this HTML can be used (...) tags will be changed ..." is ok.

Comment: Ok, now I don't understand. By "this HTML will not be changed" I meant that if you load it to CKEditor and then retrieve data back from CKEditor, you'll still have two figcaptions - one before and one after image. However, as I wrote in my previous comment, you need to configure the ACF first.

Comment: hum... Well, my procedure perhaps express better: 1) go to [demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo#widgets); 2) at "Image Tool" click "source code"; 3) add more one *figcaption* and remove *class* attribute; 4) click source-code; 5) click source-code, and see that all destroyed.

Comment: So I'll repeat it again: CKEditor strips `figure` and `figcaption`, because they are not allowed in default configuration. Read about the [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) to learn how to configure it.

Comment: Yes, and I repeat again: your text "this HTML will not be changed" is false, is wrong, the HTML will be changed (!), as you say, "CKEditor strips" the tags.

Comment: @PeterKrauss I think he means "this HTML will not be changed into a widget" or "this HTML will not be upcast".

Comment: Yes, nothing like knowing how to speak English! This is not my language... Can you edit the Reinmar's phrase for another readers?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. I meant that neither parser, nor any other filtering or processing mechanism will modify this HTML. I don't know how can I be clearer about that.

Comment: @Reinmar: can i enable caption image option true by default